# How can I pass a Variable to this run() function?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, runnable, picasso

The class I am talking about here comes from the Picasso Lib for Android.
I have a variable inside this function called "ImageName".
However I cant seem to figure out how to pass a parameter to the function to change that variables name. I have tried extending the Target class but I still seem to get errors and I am not advanced enough to know what I am doing wrong.

```
private Target target = new Target() {
    @Override
    public void onBitmapLoaded(final Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from)
{
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                File file = new File(
                        Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()
                                + ImageName + ."jpg");//+ "/saved.jpg");
                try {
                    file.createNewFile();
                    FileOutputStream ostream = new FileOutputStream(file);
                    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG,100,ostream);
                    ostream.close();
                }
                catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }).start();
    }

    @Override
    public void onBitmapFailed(Drawable errorDrawable) {}

    @Override
    public void onPrepareLoad(Drawable placeHolderDrawable) {}
};
```

//WHAT I HAVE COME UP WITH in the mean time...

```
public interface TargetImageName extends Target
{

    public void TargetImageName(String ImageName);

    @Override
    void onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from);

    @Override
    void onBitmapFailed(Drawable errorDrawable);

    @Override
    void onPrepareLoad(Drawable placeHolderDrawable);
}

private TargetImageName target2 = new TargetImageName() {
    String name;
    @Override
    public void TargetImageName(String ImageName) {
        name = ImageName;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBitmapLoaded(final Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from) {
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                File file = new File(
                        Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()
                                + name);//+ "/saved.jpg");
                try {
                    file.createNewFile();
                    FileOutputStream ostream = new FileOutputStream(file);
                    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG,100,ostream);
                    ostream.close();
                }
                catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }).start();
    }

    @Override
    public void onBitmapFailed(Drawable errorDrawable) {}

    @Override
    public void onPrepareLoad(Drawable placeHolderDrawable) {}
};
```

Comment: Extending class Target is the way to include parameters in its constructor. What errors have you found then?

Comment: Extending the Target interface was a shot in the dark but they way I did it here does not seem to work anyway . I cant instantiate TargetImageName target2 = TargetImageName("ASD){}  just gives a "Cannot be Applied" error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot pass anything to `run()` as it takes no arguments. What you should do is simply extend `Runnable` and pass whatever you need via constructor:

```
public class MyRunnable implements Runnable {
     protected Integer mFoo;

     public MyRunnable(Integer foo) { 
        mFoo = foo;
     }

     @Override
     public void run() {
          // access mFoo when you need it
           ...
     }
}
```

and then

```
...
 new Thread(new MyRunnable(...)) {
    ...
```

Comment: Sorry did not see your Reply in time for my Edit on the Question : /

Comment: Not sure what's the problem but you can always rollback your edit to the question if you think that would be helpful. Just click on "[edited XX mins ago](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/31854285/revisions)"

Comment: When I do that it seems to work in the Function BUT the Runnable gives an error saying " No interface expected here" ? Where do I use that code?

Comment: should be `implements

Comment: Haha oh whow that is so much easier then I thought it was going to be ! 
Thanks allot Marcin!

Comment: Yea no worries I keep on pressing Enter to go next line and then I post only half my comment >.< !

Answer (score 0):

Instead of another interface, create a class which implements Target.

```
public class TargetImageName implements Target
    {
        String name;
        public  TargetImageName(String ImageName) {
            name = ImageName;
        }
        @Override
        public void onBitmapFailed(Drawable errorDrawable) {

        ...}
        @Override
        public void onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from) {
        ...}

        @Override
        public void onPrepareLoad(Drawable placeHolderDrawable) {
        ...}
    }
```

Now create an object and pass it as a `Picasso` callback object

```
Picasso.with(getActivity()).load(<url>).into(new TargetImageName(<parameter>));
```